# Quasar framework QLayout weird yellow border on key press

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, quasar

I'm working on a quasar framework, electron.js project, and I found this weird bug when press a key then the application frame has a yellow border, and is impossible to override or make disappear, or select with devtools, since when you unfocus the window it will disappear.

If I comment QLayout component then it stop's happening so it has to be something with that component.

Im using linux mint, haven't tested this bug in other OS.

[image]

EDIT:

Minimal reproducible example:

- Create a quasar project
- Add electron.js mode
- Run project
- Click on app window
- Press a key

Comment: This looks like Chrome's focus outline, which would mean that your main component is keyboard-focusable (have you tried `outline: none;` in CSS?). Anyhow, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] for others to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner That was it! Thanks. The minimal reproducible example is just creating a new quasar project with electron.js. Put this answer below so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this weird outline. I could reproduce it with [Quasar's Layout Builder](https://quasar.dev/layout-builder): Unselect header, footer and drawers, then press any key. A blue outline appears. Not sure if it is ok in general to remove it with `outline: none`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, put in the element CSS

```
outline: none;
```